# Maven repository usage to download artifacts

Tags: maven

I have added a repository to download artifacts and I have seen maven using that repository to download artifacts, but only for particular artifacts of that repository maven tries to download from mvn central repository. When I chek that artifact on added repository it's available. What could be the issue ? In which situations maven tries to download from central repository ?

Specific issues is highlighted in ,
[Magnolia Demo project mvn build failed due to not able to fetch magnolia-setproperty-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368406/magnolia-demo-project-mvn-build-failed-due-to-not-able-to-fetch-magnolia-setprop)

Answer (score 0):

All the Maven dependencies are first downloaded from your local repository, then if they are not found, Maven will try in any remote repository that you define in your POM file or the settings.xml and for last it will try to download from Maven Central.

Comment: Thanks,I have noticed repository need to added to settings.xml and to the pom.